# Access multi selection list box as a criteria to INSERT, UPDATE OR DELETE records from a table

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

For a database with this schema (a product may belong to one or more categories):

```
Item_category(product, category_name)
Category(category_name)
```

Will it be possible for me to build a multi-selection list box (List box data source from the Category relation) using an Access form and then highlighting the categories that the product belongs to (by querying the Item_category table), and at the same time letting users select new categories or deselect highlighted categories so that when an "Update" button is pressed, VBA code will automatically determine either `INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE` queries are needed to update the `Item_category` table?

How can I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've generally done this type of interface using a form which looks very much like the "Which fields do you want on your form?" in the Form Wizard.  Where you have the Table/Query list of Available Fields in the table in the listbox on the left hand side and the Selected Fields in the listbox on the right hand side.   Along with the move left and right command buttons in the middle.   The users quite like this interface.

**Added:** Note that the left hand listbox contains all the category records which aren't present in the products category table.   So a category would be present in one or the other listbox but never both.

You very likely will want to use the Multi Select property of the listbox.  If you hit the help on that field in the property sheet it should lead you to a page which mentions the ItemsSelected collection.  Visit that page for sample code on how to read all the items selected by the user.  Or visit http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa196172%28v=office.11%29.aspx.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand what you mean but is there a simpler way to determine whether `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` is required in my query? (Since a user can modify the item by binding one or more category to the item, deleting one or more category to the item or simply update the category (categories) that the item belongs to)

Comment: If it's on the right hand listbox, they've selected one or more records and clicked on the left arrow command button then it's a delete.  If it's on the left hand listbox and they click on the right hand arrow then it's an insert.   But I also forgot one important detail.  See the middle paragraph I added.

Comment: Not that I care very much about the Stack Overflow point system nevertheless it's considered good manners, if reasonable, to accept the best response.

Comment: Sorry I am quite new to Stack Overflow.

Comment: No problem.  Please let us know how this UI worked for you and your users.